# Program Stopped working when inserting data using linked list

Tags: c++, class

I've been working on a program that use class. I know that setter and getter are used to accessed private members, but what if I input data in class using a `getInput()` do I still need the setter and getter?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

void printList();
void delete_end_node();

struct list
{
    list *head, *tail;
    list *next;
};

class node 
{ 
    private:
        string name; // Name 
        int age; // Age in integer 
        float height; // In meters  

    public:
        node *next; // Pointer to next node 
        node *head, *tail;
        node *start_ptr = NULL; // Start Pointer (root)
        node *temp;
        node *temp2;

        node()
        {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }

        void printList();
        void delete_end_node();
        void search();

        void getInput()
        {

            int total;
            cout<< "How many you want to input? ";
            cin>> total;
            for (int i=0; i<total; i++)
            {
                temp = new node;
                cout << "Please enter the name of the person: "; 
                cin >> temp->name; 
                cout << "Please enter the age of the person : "; 
                cin >> temp->age; 
                cout << "Please enter the height of the person : "; 
                cin >> temp->height; 

                temp->next = NULL; // Sets the node to be the last node
                if (start_ptr == NULL) 
                    start_ptr = temp;
                else
                { 
                    temp2 = start_ptr; // We know temp2 is not NULL - list not empty! 
                    while (temp2->next != NULL) // The loop will terminate when temp2 
                        temp2 = temp2->next;    // points to the last node in the list 
                                                // Move to next link in chain 
                    temp2->next = temp; // Sets the pointer from that last node to point 
                                        // to the node that has just declared
                }
            }

        }

    //Constructor
    node(string node_name, int node_age, float node_height)
    {name = node_name; age = node_age; height = node_height;}

    // SET
    setName(string node_name){name = node_name;}
    setAge(int node_age){age = node_age;}
    setHeight(float node_height){height = node_height;}
    // GET
    string getName(){return name;}
    int getAge(){return age;}
    float getHeight(){return height;}   

}; 


node *start_ptr = NULL; // Start Pointer (root)

int main()
{
    node *temp;
    node *temp2;
    node obj;
    int choice;
    cout << "MAIN MENU:\n\n1. ADD\n2. DISPLAY\n3. DELETE\n4. EXIT\n";
    cin>> choice;
    system("cls");

    while(choice!=4)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                cout<<"ADD"<<endl;
                obj.getInput(); // This where it stops
                system ("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                cout<<"DISPLAY"<<endl;
                temp->printList();
                system ("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                cout<<"Deleting the last node";
                temp->delete_end_node();

                temp->printList();
                //Deleting all the nodes
                temp2 = start_ptr; // We know temp2 is not NULL - list not empty! 
                while (temp2 != NULL) 
                {
                    start_ptr = start_ptr->next;
                    delete temp2;       // points to the last node in the list 
                    temp2 = start_ptr;
                }
                system ("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                cout<< "EXIT...";
                break;
            }

            default:
                continue;
        } // END SWITCH CASE
    } //END WHILE
    return 0;
} // END MAIN
```

Answer (score 2):

You never *need* a setter and getter.  They are a common pattern, more common in interpreted bytecode languages like Java and C#.

As a general rule, you generally aren't going to need it; don't write code you aren't using.

The process of working out why your code isn't working is called "debugging".  You launch your program in a "debugger" and find the spot where it doesn't work, or follow it step by step examining the state.  You can examine the state of the program and try to spot things that you don't expect, like pointers being null or memory being corrupted or uninitialized.

[Here is a youtube lecture on how to debug a C++ program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCH9nWGCv6k); it may help (I literally googled "how to debug C++" and linked the first video, I hope it doesn't suck).  Stackoverflow isn't a "debug my program for me" service.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why getters/setters are more common in interpreted bytecode languages?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is an observation?  Maybe becaues of paucity of value types in them and their typical 2x-3x performance overhead cost.  I mean, you'll get the same thing (lots of accessors) with C++ COM based code.  Both Java and C# have recently gotten less-crippled value types, maybe things will change (or have changed since I last played with them)